# How to merge two observables in specific manner with RxJava?

Tags: reactive-programming, rx-java

I'm new in RxJava and ran into next problem:
I have two streams:

`Stream 1: -●-●-●-●-●-●-●-●-●-●-●->`

`Stream 2: -▲-▲-▲-▲-▲-▲-▲-▲-▲-▲-▲->`

and I need the third stream combined from that two streams in next way:

`Stream 3: -●-●-▲-●-●-▲-●-●-▲-●-●-▲->`

It means that we have two elements from S1 and element from S2, two elems from S1 and elem from S2...

How it can be done with RxJava?

Answer (score 2):

`Zip` is half the answer, `buffer` is the another half:

```
Observable<String> source1 = Observable.just("●").repeat(8);
Observable<String> source2 = Observable.just("▲").repeat(4);

Observable.zip(source1.buffer(2), source2, (a, b) -> {
    return Observable.just(a.get(0), a.get(1), b);
})
.flatMap(v -> v)
.doOnSubscribe(() -> System.out.print('-'))
.subscribe(v -> {
    System.out.print(v);
    System.out.print("-");
}, Throwable::printStackTrace,
() -> System.out.println(">"));
```

Comment: but if items in `source1` are over, zipped Observable won't emit items that left in `source2`. How can I don't lose them?

Comment: @dmitriyzaitsev did you get the answer how to not loose latest `source2` items?

Comment: @KamilSeweryn, no. As far as I found out, it cannot be achieved with standard tools. We need to write our own operator.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at zip,  it allows you to pass in 2 observables and a function to apply to each item emitted by either observable.
http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/zip.html